# Como obtener el valor de un atributo en json que tiene como nombre un numero en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, atributos

he intentado acceder a un archivo json local, donde llamo a una respuesta que ahi en cierto año, pero al llamarlo me lo toma como numero, así "datos.data[0].estados.2019", pero al ser numerico el 2019 no lo toma y trae error.

nose como llamarlo...

me podrian ayudar?? 
se los agradecería

codigo:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Content/archivo.json',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (datos) {
            var dat = datos.data[0].estados.2019;
            $('#estado').html(dat);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hola @Alex K , haz hecho un `console.log(datos)` ? , haciendo eso te dará una idea de como tendrías que acceder a la data, por otra parte, es muy raro que la propiedad del objeto tenga por identificador un número , yo que tu reviso eso. Y lo otro sería que pongas acá el json que tienes para ver como se podría trabajar y darte ayuda. Saludos!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar el símbolo de brackets`[]` para acceder las propiedades de tu objeto.

Ejemplo:

```js
const datos = {
  2019: 'Test'
}
console.log(datos[2019])
```